# Changing cck fields on content page edit with taxonomy

Tags: drupal-6

How can I change the field options on a page edit with taxonomy terms, like week 1 , you have some cck fields configurated a certain way, week 2 you have another set of fields, all displayed by Ajax, so when you are saving a page , it updates a specified ulr content with the term you have selected.

Taxonomy = Week 1

--Some text field content--

Taxonomy = week 2

--Some other field content--

ect..

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? It sounds like you really want serperate content types. Doing as you described REALLY isn't a good idea, if it's even possible.

Comment: What you want then is something like a menu item content type, and use a view for the actual menu.

Comment: Actually i'm making a site for a restaurant ownner and he wants to update it's menu every week, it is something like this http://gearaudition.com/test/Exemple_menu.jpg. So changing the number at the top would display another sets of preselected fields for the given week. The only solution that I found was making different page and publish & unpublish them every week. But the problem is that i find this fonction a little bit complicated for him, as he'll have to select one page unpublish it and choose another one and publish it, i would only like him to choose from a drop down list of weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been given the answer, "conditional fields" module. YESS!